# ModuleNotFoundError in custom module on azure webapps

Tags: python, azure, importerror, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I'm trying to run an app.py made with python3.7(flask) in azure webapps.
I deployed app.py and sleep_model.py that app.py uses from github.
(app.py imports sleep_model.py, and sleep_model.py imports numpy.)
 
 
Then I got this error on azure log stream:
'''

```
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536802053Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/app.py", line 15, in <module>  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536806954Z    　 import sleep_model  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536811454Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/sleep_model.py", line 1, in <module>  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536816354Z    　 import numpy as np  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536821154Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

'''

What should I modify for sleep_model.py to successfully import numpy?

The structure of my resources:
Subscription - Resource Group - App Service
Free (F1)    - sleepapitest2  - sleepapitest2

App Service Plan: appsvc_linux_centralus (F1: Free)

System Info:
OS version: Unix 4.4.0.128
64 bit system: True
64 bit process: True
Processor count: 1

The structure of my wwwroot is this:

'''

```
img  
pythonenv3.8  
tests  
__pycache__  
app.py  
ConceptofFunctionEvaluate.md  
oryx-manifest.toml  
README.md  
requirements.txt  
sleep_model.py
```

'''

The codes inside app.py is this:

app.py
'''

```
from flask import abort, Flask, jsonify, request  
from werkzeug.exceptions import BadRequest  
from logging import getLogger, StreamHandler, FileHandler, DEBUG, Formatter  
import sleep_model

(application codes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

'''

The importing part of sleep_model.py is this:

sleep:model.py
'''

```
import numpy as np
```

'''

The inside of requirements.txt file is this:

requirements.text
'''

```
flask  
numpy  
logging  
werkzeug
```

'''

In the GitHub Action logs, it appears that numpy is installed successfuly.

GitHub Actions > build-and-deploy > Build using AppService-Buld
'''

```
Run azure/appservice-build@v1
  with:
    platform: python
  env:
    pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.6/x64
/usr/bin/docker run --name c27d3147d163fea80a45388665e71d8a738aa0_a89863 --label c27d31 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e pythonLocation -e INPUT_PLATFORM -e INPUT_SOURCE-DIRECTORY -e INPUT_PLATFORM-VERSION -e INPUT_OUTPUT-DIRECTORY -e HOME -e GITHUB_JOB -e GITHUB_REF -e GITHUB_SHA -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER -e GITHUB_RUN_ID -e GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER -e GITHUB_ACTOR -e GITHUB_WORKFLOW -e GITHUB_HEAD_REF -e GITHUB_BASE_REF -e GITHUB_EVENT_NAME -e GITHUB_WORKSPACE -e GITHUB_ACTION -e GITHUB_EVENT_PATH -e RUNNER_OS -e RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE -e RUNNER_TEMP -e RUNNER_WORKSPACE -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN -e ACTIONS_CACHE_URL -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/sleep_apnea_api/sleep_apnea_api":"/github/workspace" c27d31:47d163fea80a45388665e71d8a738aa0  "" "python" "" ""

No source directory was provided -- the root of the repository ('GITHUB_WORKSPACE' environment variable) will be built: '/github/workspace'
No output directory was provided
Platform provided: 'python'
No platform version provided -- Oryx will determine the version.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   139  100   139    0     0   1564      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1579

Running command 'oryx build /github/workspace --platform python --enable-dynamic-install'
Build orchestrated by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues

Oryx Version      : 0.2.20200312.2, Commit: d1cf6b4a89345b6a7d0dc25d0fbd67860862ee18, ReleaseTagName: 20200312.2
Build Operation ID: |NIcJoHTZQ4M=.3e27c1c4_
Repository Commit : a0f0cc373a543d1d26feb535d6ef12479abf0ff9


Source directory     : /github/workspace
Destination directory: /github/workspace
Python Version: /opt/python/3.8.2/bin/python3
Python Virtual Environment: pythonenv3.8
Creating virtual environment ...
Activating virtual environment ...

Upgrading pip...
WARNING: The directory '/github/home/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
WARNING: The directory '/github/home/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/0c/d01aa759fdc501a58f431eb594a17495f15b88da142ce14b5845662c13f3/pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.2.3
    Uninstalling pip-19.2.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-19.2.3
Successfully installed pip-20.0.2
Done in 2 sec(s).
Running pip install...
[10:50:41+0000] Collecting flask
[10:50:41+0000]   Downloading Flask-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
[10:50:41+0000] Collecting numpy
[10:50:41+0000]   Downloading numpy-1.18.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (20.6 MB)
[10:50:42+0000] Collecting werkzeug
[10:50:42+0000]   Downloading Werkzeug-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
[10:50:42+0000] Collecting Jinja2>=2.10.1
[10:50:43+0000]   Downloading Jinja2-2.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
[10:50:43+0000] Collecting click>=5.1
[10:50:43+0000]   Downloading click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
[10:50:43+0000] Collecting itsdangerous>=0.24
[10:50:43+0000]   Downloading itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
[10:50:43+0000] Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23
[10:50:43+0000]   Downloading MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (32 kB)
[10:50:43+0000] Installing collected packages: MarkupSafe, Jinja2, werkzeug, click, itsdangerous, flask, numpy
[10:50:46+0000] Successfully installed Jinja2-2.11.2 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 click-7.1.2 flask-1.1.2 itsdangerous-1.1.0 numpy-1.18.3 werkzeug-1.0.1
Done running pip install.

Removing existing manifest file
Creating a manifest file...
Manifest file created.

Done in 11 sec(s).
```

'''

But log streams in azure, 'ModuleNotFoundError' occures:
log stream
'''

```
2020-04-28T10:55:11.375437745Z Updated PYTHONPATH to ':/home/site/wwwroot/pythonenv3.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages'  
2020-04-28T10:55:12.774642858Z [2020-04-28 10:55:12 +0000] [38] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4  
2020-04-28T10:55:12.775951599Z [2020-04-28 10:55:12 +0000] [38] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (38)  
2020-04-28T10:55:12.776515817Z [2020-04-28 10:55:12 +0000] [38] [INFO] Using worker: sync  
2020-04-28T10:55:12.804942720Z [2020-04-28 10:55:12 +0000] [41] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 41  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536643548Z [2020-04-28 10:55:13 +0000] [41] [ERROR] Exception in worker process  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536680450Z Traceback (most recent call last):  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536687550Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536693050Z     worker.init_process()  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536697650Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536709650Z     self.load_wsgi()  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536714651Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536719551Z     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536724251Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536729151Z     self.callable = self.load()  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536734151Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536739151Z     return self.load_wsgiapp()  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536743652Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536748552Z     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536753252Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536758252Z     mod = importlib.import_module(module)  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536762952Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536767752Z     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536772452Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536777653Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536782553Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536787353Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536792153Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536797153Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536802053Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/app.py", line 15, in <module>  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536806954Z     import sleep_model  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536811454Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/sleep_model.py", line 1, in <module>  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536816354Z     import numpy as np  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.536821154Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.541040988Z [2020-04-28 10:55:13 +0000] [41] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 41)  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.640991661Z [2020-04-28 10:55:13 +0000] [38] [INFO] Shutting down: Master  
2020-04-28T10:55:13.649049717Z [2020-04-28 10:55:13 +0000] [38] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.  
2020-04-28 10:55:14.734 ERROR - Container sleepapitest2_0_c4c43b35 for site sleepapitest2 has exited, failing site start  
2020-04-28 10:55:14.736 ERROR - Container sleepapitest2_0_c4c43b35 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.  
2020-04-28 10:55:14.784 INFO  - Stoping site sleepapitest2 because it failed during startup.
```

'''

Thenk you for your concern.

Comment: as sleep.py needs numpy, 
you need to have that package in your system. Install the package using ```pip install numpy``` and other modules that would be missing.

Comment: @InderjeetSingh

Comment: @InderjeetSingh thank you for your comment. which directory should I run 'pip install numpy' on azure webapps? I did 'pip install numpy' in '/home' directory on my webapp's advanced tools > bash, and run 'pip list', but the list doesn't include numpy. thank you.

Comment: If you are using virtual environment using venv then you need to issue the command in that particular directory.
I would assume you run app.py using ```python app.py```.
 ;in the same directory do ```python -m pip install numpy``` ;the same python executable will be used.

Comment: @InderjeetSingh thank you for your reply. I don't use 'python app.py' when I run the app.py. The app.py starts automatically after deployment from github actions. I didn't use venv either. github action appears to create and activate virtual enviroment according to its logs( I saw again github action logs and added some part to my question body after your last comment)..I tried 'pip install numpy' in '/home/site/wwwroot/pythonenv3.8/bin' directory on my webapp's advanced tools > bash, and run 'pip list', but the list doesn't include numpy.

Comment: Is this solved? I have the same issue with numpy and with Flask-APScheduler on Azure Linux AppServices